# Manage Azure Namespace using Powershell

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-powershell

Using Powershell, is there a way to manage Azure Namespace without logging in to subscription?

Using Powershell, can we use Namespace **Shared Access Secret** to manage namespace (i.e. add/remove/update topics, queues and subscriptions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure powershell cmdlets require authentication. If you'd like to manage your namespace without that, you can do it via .NET code using [NamespaceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.aspx) class

Comment: Found that I can still use Powershell by creating object of NamespaceManager class and pass it the connectionstring containing Shared Access Secret.

Comment: Right. All .NET objects can be used from PS.